# How do you get these results from a function?

Tags: python

I got a simple Python tree assignment at school, but I'm stuck. How can I make function recursively?

The mains given are as follows.

```
tree_s = '(A (B (C) (D (E) (F) ) )(G (H)) (I (J (K) )))'

treeSLst = [x for x in tree_s if x != ' ']
print(treeSLst)

p = Tree()
p.build_tree(p.root, treeSLst)
print(p)
```

The following are the results that should come out:

```
ROOT--> [ A ]
A--> [ B,G,I ]
B--> [ C,D ]
D--> [ E,F ]
G--> [ H ]
I--> [ J ]
J--> [ K ]
```

Printed parts are given so there's no problem.

```
def build_tree(self, parent, treeSLst):
    #index = -1

    for token in treeSLst:
        #index += 1
        if token == '(':
            #n = Node(treeSLst[index+1])
            #parent.add_child(n)
            #self.build_tree(n, treeSLst[index+1:])
        if token == ')':
            #return
```

The part where I marked # is the code I tried. Of course, it looked weird.
The rest is given.

It needs to be implemented recursively.
Maybe I should use "self.build_tree()", Help please!

Comment: When you recurse, the current call needs to skip over all the tokens that the recursive call processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will process the nested tokens multiple times. The recursive call will process them, then the caller's `for` loop will process them again.

Instead of a `for` loop, use a `while` loop and pull each token off the list to process it.

```
def build_tree(self, parent, treeSLst):
    while treeSlst:
        token = treeSLst.pop(0)
        if token == '(':
            n = Node(treeSlst.pop(0))
            parent.addChild(n)
            self.build_tree(n, treeSLst)
        elif token == ')':
            return
```

Comment: Wow, I should have used 'while' as a given code, but it was given as 'for' by mistake.
And yet, you've given it the right way.
I get the results I want. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `for` is the normal way to iterate over a list, but it doesn't provide a way to skip elements when you process them in the recursive call.